# Improving a Web App's Performance

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-jk

My web app, an exploded `WAR`, is hosted by `Apache` (static content) and `Tomcat` (dynamic content) via `mod_jk`. Optionally, there's an ActiveMQ component of this system, but it's currently not being used.

As I understand, each HTTP request will hit Apache. If it's a dynamic content request, Apache will forward the request to Tomcat via mod_jk. To fulfill this request, Tomcat will start a new thread to do the work.

I'm running the app on a 6-core, 12 GB RAM machine.

Besides using the ActiveMQ component, how can I improve my system's performance? Also, please correct me if I'm misstating how Apache and Tomcat communicate.

Comment: Are you having a problem or are you just looking to optimize for fun?

Comment: Having a problem. App currently loads too slowly.

Comment: There is this rampant problem on SO where people say my app is slow.... fix it. You need to be specific. Like: Its slow when serving 10k requests, the average request time is 600ms and we would like it at 100ms and we have tried these specifics. Tomcat and apache probably have very little to do with the performance compared to whatever persistence libraries/layer your using. Also instead of the load or benchmarks you gave specifics of the machine which mean jack squat.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, Adam Gent. My problem is that I've never run load testing, so I didn't know enough to state my benchmarks, expected bottlenecks and attempts to resolve, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (unhappyWithSitePerformance) {
  executeLoadTest();
  identifyBiggestBottleneck(); // e.g. what breaks first
  fixIdentifiedBottleneck();
}
```

There is no blank silver bullet to provide. You should make sure your load test simulates realistic user behaviour and define the number of (virtual) users you want your server to handle within given answering time. Then tune your server until your goal is met.

Common parameters to look for are

- memory consumption
- CPU consumption (e.g. certain algorithms)
- I/O saturation - e.g. communication to the database, general HTTP traffic saturating the network adapter
- Database or backend answering time - e.g. sometimes you'll have to tune the backend, not the webserver itself.